# How to get the pipeline object in Scrapy spider

Tags: python, mongodb, scrapy

I have use the **mongodb** to store the data of the crawl.

Now I want to query the last date of the data, that I can continue crawl the data and not need restart it from the begin of the url list.(url, which can determined by the date, like: /2014-03-22.html)

I want only one connection object to take the database operation, which is in pipeline.

So, I want to know how can I get the pipeline object(not new one) in the spider.

Or, any better solution for incremental update...

Thanks in advance.

Sorry, for my poor english...
Just sample now:

```
# This is my Pipline
class MongoDBPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self, mongodb_db=None, mongodb_collection=None):
        self.connection = pymongo.Connection(settings['MONGODB_SERVER'], settings['MONGODB_PORT'])
        ....
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        ....
    def get_date(self):
        ....
```

And the spider:

```
class Spider(Spider):
    name = "test"
    ....

    def parse(self, response):
        # Want to get the Pipeline object
        mongo = MongoDBPipeline() # if take this way, must a new Pipeline object
        mongo.get_date()          # In scrapy, it must have a Pipeline object for the spider
                                  # I want to get the Pipeline object, which created when scrapy started.
```

Ok, just don't want to new a new object....I admit I am an OCD..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Scrapy Pipeline has an [open_spider](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#open_spider) method that gets executed after  the spider is initialized.  You can pass a reference to the database connection, the get_date() method, or the Pipeline itself, to your spider.  An example of the latter with your code is:

```
# This is my Pipline
class MongoDBPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self, mongodb_db=None, mongodb_collection=None):
        self.connection = pymongo.Connection(settings['MONGODB_SERVER'], settings['MONGODB_PORT'])
        ....

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        ....
    def get_date(self):
        ....

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        spider.myPipeline = self
```

Then, in the spider:

```
class Spider(Spider):
    name = "test"

    def __init__(self):
        self.myPipeline = None

    def parse(self, response):
        self.myPipeline.get_date()
```

I don't think the `__init__()` method is necessary here, but I put it here to show that open_spider replaces it after initialization.

Answer (score 1):

According to the scrapy [Architecture Overview](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html):

> The Item Pipeline is responsible for processing the items once they
>   have been extracted (or scraped) by the spiders.

Basically that means that, first, scrapy spiders are working, then extracted items are going to the pipelines - no way to go backwards.

One possible solution would be, in the pipeline itself, check if the Item you've scraped is already in the database.

Another workaround would be to keep the list of urls you've crawled in the database, and, in the spider, check if you've already got the data from a url.

Since I'm not sure what do you mean by "start from the beginning" - I cannot suggest anything specific.

Hope at least this information helped.

Comment: I mean that the website url I crawl for is ordered by the date, and I can determine which url I need crawl by the date.

Comment: Is the way to keep the list of urls can get the Pipeline object? Or, need new a database connection object to check if it exits?

Comment: @Pitty sorry, I don't understand what are you asking about. Could you provide a small example? Thanks.

Comment: @Pitty yeah, you can instantiate a database connection inside the spider - get the list of urls you've already scraped, then in `parse` check that if the `response.url` is in the list or not. Does it make sense?

Comment: I know I can do like this, and already for it, just don't know how to make the connection in one connection object...When a spider is ran, scrapy must init the Pipeline. And in the pipeline I created a connection. I want to know, if can I get the connection(init in pipeline), not new one. Mean that all in this crawl, just created one connection, not two..