# How to access pipeline database pool in scrapy spider

Tags: python, scrapy

First, here is what I'm trying to do:

I have an XMLFeedSpider that goes through a list of products (the nodes) in an XML file and creates items that are saved to my database in a pipeline.  The first time I see a product I need to create requests to do some scraping on the url field of the product to get images, etc.  On subsequent reads of the feed if I see the same product I don't want to waste time/resources doing this and just want to skip making these extra requests.  To see which products to skip I need to access my database to see if the product exists.

Here are various ways I could think of to do this:

1. Just create a db request for each product within the spider.  This
   seems like a bad idea.
2. In my item store pipeline I'm already creating a database pool as follows:
   `dbpool = adbapi.ConnectionPool('psycopg2', cp_max=2, cp_min=1, **dbargs)` and it would seem more efficient to just use that so I'm not constantly creating new database connects.  I don't know how to access the instantiated pipeline class though in my spider (that is probably more of a general python question).
   Note: this guy is basically asking this same question but didn't really get the answer he was looking for. [How to get the pipeline object in Scrapy spider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23105590/how-to-get-the-pipeline-object-in-scrapy-spider)
3. Maybe before starting the crawl load all of the product urls into memory so I can compare them when processing the products?  Where would be a good place to do this?
4. Other suggestion?

Update: this is my pipeline with db pool

```
class PostgresStorePipeline(object):
    """A pipeline to store the item in a MySQL database.
    This implementation uses Twisted's asynchronous database API.
    """

    def __init__(self, dbpool):
        print "Opening connection pool..."
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        self.dbpool = dbpool

    @classmethod
    def from_settings(cls, settings):
        dbargs = dict(
            host=settings['MYSQL_HOST'],
            database=settings['MYSQL_DBNAME'],
            user=settings['MYSQL_USER'],
            password=settings['MYSQL_PASSWD'],
            #charset='utf8',
            #use_unicode=True,
        )
        dbpool = adbapi.ConnectionPool('psycopg2', cp_max=2, cp_min=1, **dbargs)
        return cls(dbpool)
```

Comment: for items you mean urls right?

Comment: not urls, I guess the proper terminology would be 'nodes' of the xml.  i can see how saying items is confusing.  there is one xml file and in it are many nodes, each of which I'm saving as an item.  I will update the question to make this more clear

Comment: yeah but you want to avoid are the urls inside those nodes right? to do multiple requests to the same url on future jobs

Comment: yes, I want to avoid urls in the nodes for which I've already saved the node to the database on a previous crawl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you mean `URL` by `item`, remember that for `scrapy` an `item` is a data output, and a `pipeline` is a mechanism to deal with those output items.

Of course you don't need to open many connections to do your db queries, but you will have to do the necessary queries. It depends on how many records you have on your database to only do one query or one per `URL`, you should test which one is better on your case.

I would recommend setting your own [`DUPEFILTER_CLASS`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#dupefilter-class) with something like:

```
from scrapy.dupefilters import RFPDupeFilter

class DBDupeFilter(RFPDupeFilter):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # self.cursor = .....                       # instantiate your cursor
        super(DBDupeFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def request_seen(self, request):
        if self.cursor.execute("myquery"):          # if exists
            return True
        else:
            return super(DBDupeFilter, self).request_seen(request)

    def close(self, reason):
        self.cursor.close()                         # close  your cursor
        super(DBDupeFilter, self).close(reason)
```

**UPDATE**

The problem here is that the `DUPEFILTER_CLASS` doesn't offer the spider on its `request_seen` object or even to get in on the constructor, so I think your best shot is with a [Downloader Middleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#downloader-middleware), where you can raise a `IgnoreRequest` exception.

1. Instantiate the db connection on the spider, you could do this on the spider itself (the constructor), or you can also add it through a signal on the Middleware or Pipeline, we'll add it on the Middleware:

   ```
   from scrapy.exceptions import IgnoreRequest

   class DBMiddleware(object):

       def __init__(self):
           pass

       @classmethod
       def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
           o = cls()
           crawler.signals.connect(o.spider_opened, signal=signals.spider_opened)
           return o

       def spider_opened(self, spider):
           spider.dbpool = adbapi.ConnectionPool('psycopg2', cp_max=2, cp_min=1, **dbargs)

       def process_request(self, request, spider):
           if spider.dbpool... # check if request.url inside the database
               raise IgnoreRequest()
   ```
2. Now on your Pipeline, remove the instantiation of `dbpool` and get it from the `spider` argument when necessary, remember than `process_item` receives the item and the spider as argument, so you should be able to use `spider.dbpool` to check your db connection.
3. Remember to [activate your middleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#activating-a-downloader-middleware).

That way you should only be doing one instance of the db connection inside the spider object.

Comment: While this could be another way of achieving my end goal I'd still be creating an additional connection to my database besides the connection pool I've already made in the pipeline.  My question is more about how to connect to that existing pool, whether it be in my spider, a dup filter like this or otherwise

Comment: I added the pertinent bits of my pipeline code.  I believe scrapy has a manager for item pipelines I'm just not sure how to access it or if that even makes sense

Comment: ok, that just got interesting then, please check the updated answer.

Comment: I think your update is a great option the only thing is if I remove the pool instantiation from the pipeline then is it true that my other spiders running concurrently via scrapyd won't be able to share a global database pool on the pipeline?  Or am I wrong and each spider scheduled via scrapyd will have it's database pipeline instantiated anyway?

Comment: the pipeline was being instantiated by every process (job).

Comment: ah, good to know.  then moving it to the spider really shouldn't matter (and I should probably just look into creating a pool outside of scrapy like pgbouncer).  I'll accept your answer but can you please add why the spider can't access the instantiated pipeline if I wanted to leave the pipeline alone and do the filtering while I'm processing the products?

Comment: because a Pipeline doesn't know about Requests, it only handles every output Scrapy `item`. 
The spider can access the pipeline, is the middleware that can't access the pipeline in this case, so it is better to share the object through the spider as both can access it.